# if statement not returning desired append to overall list

Tags: python, loops, csv, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm attempting to create a new category in my list based on the price of an application. If the price equals 0 then the new category will list the application as 'free.' If the application is equal to or greater than 50, then the new category will list the application as 'very expensive.'

When I run the following code, my new list appears to have the desired section called 'price label' for the first row which would essentially be column headers. However, the subsequent rows / parts of the list do not contain the desired price categories: 'free', 'affordable', 'expensive', etc...

Can someone please tell me why I'm not seeing the desired categories of 'free', 'affordable', expensive', etc...

Thank you in advance.

```
opened_file = open('AppleStore.csv')
from csv import reader
read_file = reader(opened_file)
apps_data = list(read_file)

for app in apps_data[1:]:
    price = float(app[4])
    if price == 0:
        app.append('free')
    elif price > 0 and price < 20:
        app.append('affordable')
    elif price >= 20 and price < 50: 
        app.append('expensive')
    elif price >= 50: 
        app.append('very expensive')

apps_data[0].append('price_label')
```

Comment: Your iterating variable `app` is the same as a list variable you're trying to append to - initialize a list and choose another variable name.

Comment: I'm trying to append the price categories: 'free', 'expensive', etc... to the original list ```apps_data```. But I don't think I can append directly to the ```apps_data``` list. Therefore, I was using the iterating variable ```app```, to hit each row/app of the original list. Is there no way to accomplish this, beyond creating a new list. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see whats the error. The code works perfectly fine for me.
Also if you want to access vaiables in the original **apps_data** list you can use **enumerate**

```
for x,app in enumerate(apps_data[1:]):
```

I have attached the output below

```
from csv import reader

with open('data.csv','r') as f:
    read_file = reader(f)
    apps_data = list(read_file)

for app in apps_data[1:]:
    price = float(app[4])
    print(price)
    if price == 0:
        app.append('free')
    elif price > 0 and price < 20:
        app.append('affordable')
    elif price >= 20 and price < 50: 
        app.append('expensive')
    elif price >= 50: 
        app.append('very expensive')

apps_data[0].append('price_label')
```

And the output was

> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'price_label']
>   ['0.158910465', '0.471050439', '0.57616592', '0.73310126', '22', 'expensive']
>   ['0.551014295', '0.366737111', '0.199838786', '0.58817097', '54', 'very expensive']
>   ['0.466420839', '0.691756584', '0.282783984', '0.585577806', '96', 'very expensive']
>   ['0.17755358', '0.836570041', '0.950988799', '0.08555555', '77', 'very expensive']
>   ['0.511195256', '0.02926122', '0.250221844', '0.811879858', '96', 'very expensive']
>   ['0.905874282', '0.377772593', '0.461482911', '0.161167257', '80', 'very expensive']
>   ['0.20806536', '0.983685005', '0.024045729', '0.36432202', '45', 'expensive']
>   ['0.980234589', '0.417512776', '0.291544555', '0.65904768', '5', 'affordable']
>   ['0.352375065', '0.978612252', '0.1695656', '0.033074721', '54', 'very expensive']
>   ['0.128592107', '0.199429582', '0.431974287', '0.600086682', '94', 'very expensive']
>   ['0.156103725', '0.060598535', '0.259385323', '0.372274231', '60', 'very expensive']
>   ['0.97831926', '0.322897216', '0.665576639', '0.616234227', '49', 'expensive']
>   ['0.59680653', '0.062487993', '0.03078493', '0.467880813', '21', 'expensive']
>   ['0.10911428', '0.79362376', '0.417777681', '0.658541168', '85', 'very expensive']
>   ['0.234281085', '0.768671392', '0.455784293', '0.780224135', '73', 'very expensive']
>   ['0.329952824', '0.333698305', '0.737541893', '0.537251952', '85', 'very expensive']
>   ['0.471958364', '0.722226788', '0.629428645', '0.304862801', '8', 'affordable']
>   ['0.454529755', '0.124055118', '0.838332848', '0.569409642', '28', 'expensive']
>   ['0.957025298', '0.222965542', '0.831737726', '0.075038234', '91', 'very expensive']

Comment: Thank you. I think I was incorrectly splitting up the code in Jupyter Notebook, vice just doing it all in one block.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what your list looks like but what you have here will not work. For one the iterating variable app is an element of your list apps_data. You can't append to it.
Lets say your apps_data looks like apps_data-[0,1,2,3,10] so app will take on the value 0,1,2,3,10 as you iterate. Line price=float(app[4]) will through an error as app is a scalar. Perhaps you wanted price=float(apps_data[4]) which would be the value 10 in the example. You will need to initialize an empty list then append to it.